# c++ [] overloading unknown error

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, set, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload this operator to return a set from a map in a data structure I'm building using an enum and I'm running into an interesting error. I haven't been able to figure out what is causing it, any thoughts?

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class SetTable
{
  public:
    enum name { a };
    SetTable()
    {
      setMap[a] = { "foo" };
    }
    ~SetTable();
    set<string> operator [] (const name & n) const {
        return setMap.find(n);
    }

  private:
    map<name, set<string> > setMap;
};

#endif

int main() {

  SetTable s;

  auto it = s[a];

 cout << *it.begin() << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

edit: Error listed below...

```
In file included from SetTable.cpp:1:0:
SetTable.h:21:39: error: ‘operator[]’ function uses ‘auto’ type 
specifier without trailing return type
     auto operator [] (const name & n) const {
                                   ^
SetTable.h:21:39: note: deduced return type only available with - std=c++14 
or -std=gnu++14
SetTable.h: In function ‘int main()’:
SetTable.h:37:8: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are 
‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘cons
t std::pair<const name, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >’)
   cout << *it.begin() << endl;
```

*Solved*
g++ -std=c++14

```
cout << *(it->second).begin() << endl;
```

Comment: well, what is the error? Knowing that it's *interesting* doesn't help us much in solving it.

Comment: Seeing the error message the problem is easy to see: `find(n)` returns the iterator pointing to the found element. You have, however, defined your function to return a `set<string>`. I am *guessing* what you probably wanted was `return setMap[n]` instead of using `find()`

Comment: I ended up writing a small test main, ran into another weird error...

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)

Comment: Be aware, though, that `setMap[n]` will insert a new element, if not yet there. If not desired: `auto i = find; return i != end ? *i : someDefault;` (notice dereferencing the iterator!).

Comment: Side note: I recomment returning a const reference for the const index operator and additionally provide a non-const iterator returning non-const reference (the references avoid unnecessary copies in many cases, the latter additionally allows to modify the values *in* the table).

Comment: (Fix to previous comment: as using a map, it is not `*i`, but `i->second`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation about [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find). But I mean, really take the time to read it.

I supposed you saw a find function was available in `std::map` and you assumed it returned the found element? Well, there's your error. Don't assume what a function does. Read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

Quickly, you'll find out that `std::map::find` doesn't return the element it found, but rather an iterator that points to that element.

Here's a snippet I took from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) (comment added by me):

```
std::map<std::string,int> my_map;
my_map["x"] = 11;
my_map["y"] = 23;

// Find the element at key 'x' and print it.
auto it = my_map.find("x");
if (it != my_map.end()) std::cout << "x: " << it->second << "\n";
```

As you can see, accessing the element with find is through an iterator.

Also be careful when the element isn't found. It will return the `end` iterator, which is kind of, in some sense, a null pointer.

I suggest you also check out `operator[]` and the `at()` function the standard map is exposing.

---

Sorry, I just read the error message you posted.

The error you paste as actually nothing to do with your code snippet.

The error is about the use of `auto` as return type, but you don't even use auto in your code you posted above.

I strongly suggest you post one specific problem, and don't blindly try solution, read the docs, follow the examples. If it's still hard, try taking a working example, and iteratively transform it to something closer to what you want.

Comment: Thank you, figured out my all too obvious mistake after reading it.

Comment: @mcdito13 I hope you clicked at least one of the three links I posted